# NDSolve and infinite expression encountered

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

When I run the following code

```
k=1/2; 
NDSolve[{f''[x] - 4 g'[x] f'[x] == 0, g''[x] - k^2/3 h'[x]^2 == 0, 
g'[x]^2 f[x] - 1/4 f'[x] g'[x] - 1 - g''[x]/4 f[x] == 0, f[0] == 1, 
f[1] == 0, g[0] == 0, h[0] == 1, g[1] == 0.9}, {f[x], g[x], 
h[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

I get the "Infinite expression 1/0 encountered" error. I am not able to understand why do I get this kind of error. Is it probably due to the boundary conditions?

[image]

**EDIT**
After the comments, I have tried to mistune the boundary conditions for `f[1]=z` and `g[0]=z` and try to see where is the problem. Here, `z` is defined recursively by `z=min + i (max - min)/steps` (see the code).

I propose the following code

```
colorlist = ColorData[35, "ColorList"];
min = 0.8;
max = 1;
steps = 10;
tmp = Table[ NDSolve[{f''[x] - 4 g'[x] f'[x] == 0, g''[x] - k^2/3 h'[x]^2 == 0, g'[x]^2 f[x] - 1/4 f'[x] g'[x] - 1 - g''[x]/4 f[x] == 0, f[0] == 1, f[1] == min + i (max - min)/steps, g[0] == min + i (max - min)/steps, h[0] == 1, g[1] == 0.9}, {f[x], g[x], h[x]}, {x, 0, 1}][[1]], {i, 1, 
steps}];
tmp2 = Table[{min + i (max - min)/steps, f[x], g[x], h[x], 
 colorlist[[i]]} /. tmp[[i]], {i, 1, steps}];
```

and the result is

[image]

I don't see where the pathology may arise. If I decrease `min` to be less the `0.8` I recover the 1/0 error.

Comment: Yes, this is due to the boundary conditions. Essentially the system is rewritten as $f''(x)=..., g''(x)=..., h'(x)=...$, and the expressions for $g''$ and $h'$ involve $1/f$.

Comment: Thank you. So, how can I solve?

Comment: You need to change how you are specifying the BCs, to stop them from being singular. Check that your equations are definitely entered in correctly.

Comment: In this case, I would try to take finite boundary conditions, with a small, but finite value of `h[1]==z` and fix its value at, say, `z=0.01`. Then you can study what happens with decreasing `z`. If the solution goes to some limit, you are on the safe side. Further, I would recommend first making this study without the equation for `h[x]`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch why do you want to fix boundary conditions for `h[1]`? I have already tried to mistune the boundary conditions for `f[1]` as you have suggested. However, the error still occurs. Then, I have tried to mistune both boundary conditions for g[0] and f[1]. The result is shown in the edited version of the answer

Comment: If you put `g'[x]^2 f[x] - 1/4 f'[x] g'[x] - 1 - g''[x]/4 (f[x] + y) == 0`  and `f[1] == z` where `y` and `z` are small numeric parameters you can play with `y` and `z`. You will see that at `y=z=0.1`you get the solution. If, al least, one of them is 10 times smaller, Mma reports a stiff system.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch thanks. I have tried to set `z=y=0.1` but I get a stiff system (see here https://ibb.co/iFcPaU). Can you give me the code you are using? thank you

Comment: Try this: `y = 0.1; z = 0.09; t = 0.;
sol = NDSolve[{f''[x] - 4 g'[x] f'[x] == 0, 
   g'[x]^2 f[x] - 1/4 f'[x] g'[x] - 1 - g''[x]/4 (f[x] + y) == 0, 
   f[0] == 1, f[1] == z, g[0] == t, g[1] == 0.9}, {f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0,
    1}]`

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch ok, you are removing the equation for `h[x]`. This works. However, if you include now `h[x]` the problem is still there.

Comment: Look, the equation for `h[x]` can be integrated later, after the solution for `g[x]` has been obtained. Your problem is not in this equation. Your system for `f` and `g` is apparently stiff.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch thank you very much! This helped